# Convert a 1-dimensional array to a two-dimensional array with the powers of the number in the array paired together

Tags: java, arrays

Edit: Im dumb as hell - Should have checked the test case propely. Problem solved - Sorry for wasting your time

The below picture demonstrates what I wish to accomplish:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
public static int[][] square(int[] array) {
    int arraySquare[][] = new int[array.length][2];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        arraySquare[i][0] = array[i];
        arraySquare[i][1] = (int) Math.pow(array[i], 2);
    }

    return arraySquare;
}
```

Where does it go wrong?

Edit:

The following @Test case is given:

```
 private final int[] array1 = {1, 2, 3};
  private final int[] array7 = {1, 4, 9};

  @Test
  public void testSquare1() {
    int[][] r = Arrays.square(array1);
    assertEquals(2, r.length);
    assertArrayEquals(array1, r[0]);
    assertArrayEquals(array7, r[1]);
  }
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code?

Comment: What's happening that you don't expect?

Comment: You should include more things, like, what you're passing in the array, what you're seeing, and where you *think* it's going wrong.  Also, catching runtime exceptions is a ***colossal*** no-no.

Comment: Add the error too

Answer (score 0):

According to the given picture, your code works fine seems to me. I do not see any problem. This is small refactoring of it (but still, it works fine):

```
public static int[][] square(int... arr) {
    int[][] res = new int[arr.length][2];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        res[i][0] = arr[i];
        res[i][1] = arr[i] * arr[i];
    }

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Assuming `Arrays` is `java.util.Arrays`, then there is no such method as `Arrays.square()` (not in JDK8 at least)
2. Array length test will result in error.

`// actual array length is 3 based on example provided 
    assertEquals(2, r.length);`

Comment: Arrays is the name of my class and square is my function above. Should have clerified that better